# how to read the aws documentation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to set credentials for dynamodb following the instruction here: https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/real-time-leaderboard-amazon-aurora-serverless-elasticache/?trk=gs_card.

Now, I want to set a credential inside const client = new DynamoDBClient({ credential here }) by following https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-dynamodb/interfaces/awsauthinputconfig.html#signer. I wasn't sure of the format of the credential inside the new DynamoDBClient method so I tried looking for the credentials code. The documentation says credential is defined in packages/middleware-signing/dist/types/configurations.d.ts:6, but I cannot find that at all.

How would I set the configuration and also know what they mean that credentials is defined in 'packages/middleware-signing/dist/types/configurations.d.ts:6'?

Answer (score 0):

All AWS SDKs have their own Developer Guides. The AWS SDK for JavaScript is no different. To learn how to work with the AWS SDK for JavaScript, refer to the Developer Guide:

[AWS SDK for JavaScript v3 Developer Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/welcome.html)

This guide contains all the information you need to get up and running with this SDK, including how to work with credentials.

TO learn how to work with the JavaScript SDK and DynamoDB, see:

[Build an app to submit data to DynamoDB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/cross-service-example-submitting-data.html)